# Getting data differences between two queries

Tags: mysql

I have two queries that result two result sets i need to compare both the result sets and need to display the differences between them.Hope i will get good support.Thank you.These are my queries

Query:1

```
SELECT distinct c.sid_ident,c.fix_ident from corept.std_sid_leg as c INNER JOIN (SELECT sid_ident, transition_ident, max(sequence_num) seq, route_type FROM corept.std_sid_leg  WHERE data_supplier='J' AND airport_ident='KBOS' GROUP BY sid_ident,transition_ident) b ON c.sequence_num=b.seq and c.sid_ident = b.sid_ident and c.transition_ident =b.transition_ident WHERE c.data_supplier='J' and c.airport_ident='KBOS';
```

Query:2

```
SELECT name,trans FROM skyplan_deploy.deploy_sids ON d.name=c.sid_ident WHERE apt = 'KBOS' AND name != trans;
```

Comparison is to be done on fields sid_ident in corept.std_sid_leg and name in skplan_deplay.deploy_sids. As Mysql does not support full outer join,I thought of using left join and right join and combine both the results.But i stuck up with this.Please help.I am getting syntax error while using left and right join.Thank you.

Comment: Provide me the syntax to combine the above two queries using left join as well as right join..so that i can union both the results

Comment: Using the search function is always a good start. Put your queries into subqueries and read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should simulate a `FULL OUTER JOIN` in MySQL.

```
SELECT * 
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
  ON A.NAME = B.NAME
WHERE B.ID IS NULL
  UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM B
LEFT OUTER JOIN A
  ON B.NAME = A.NAME
WHERE A.ID IS NULL;
```

[Compare the results of the with an actual `FULL OUTER JOIN` in SQL Server and you'll see it works.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99f00/7)

Comment: what is the significance of a.id is null?

Comment: Thank you so much..i have been stuck with this more than 3 hrs..just by placing that is null clause i solved the issue.Really thanx a lot

Comment: Have a look at [this link](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) to see the difference between a regular `FULL OUTER JOIN` and the one to return the difference.